# is g++ smart enough to optimize recursive calls of template functions?

Tags: templates, g++, compiler-optimization

I have this snippet of code:

```
template<typename... Args> class function_helper<void(Args...)>{
public:
    typedef void(*generic_function)(Args...);
    static void call(lua_State* l, generic_function func, Args... args){
        func(args...);
    }
    template<typename... retrieved> static void call(lua_State* l, generic_function func, retrieved... read){
        call(l, func, read..., to<typename std::tuple_element<sizeof...(read), std::tuple<Args...> >::type >(l, 1+sizeof...(read)));
    }
    static int wrapper(lua_State* l){
        assert(lua_isuserdata(l, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
        call(l, generic_function(lua_touserdata(l, lua_upvalueindex(1))));
        return 0;
    }
};
```

The purpose is to have a free function wrapper (with arguments list of any length), so that it's callable by lua by pushing `function_helper::wrapper`.
All works well. My "worry" is that g++ is not smart enough to understand that the recursive calls of `call` could be replaced with a single call of the like of

```
call(luastate, to<type1>(luastate, 1), to<type2>(luastate, 2), to<type3>(luastate, 3), ...);
```

My compiler is g++ 4.6.1. If you have info on g++ 4.7 or newer that would be welcome as well.

P.S.
the use of `std::tuple` is a workaround to a g++ 4.6 limitation, it cannot unpack directly a vararg template list to a vararg argument or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in #gcc @ freenode. They said yes, unless you take the pointer of function local variables. But since there's none, the answer should be yes.